# Lumped delay lines

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

I was wondering about the delay time per section of lumped-delay line. Its equation is given by

$\tau=\sqrt{LC}$

for low frequencies

what I am wondering about is if there's an intuitive explanation of why the time delay depends on the inductance. The reason why it makes sense for capacitance that, the capacitor will take time till it get fully filled and the signal travel. Is there an intuitive reason why it does depend on the inductance.

Comment: it also takes time to "fill" up an inductor with magnetic energy and also to reduce that energy because current has "inertia".

Comment: why energy can't flow before filling the inductor or capacitor

Comment: It does flow just less in the beginning when the network is filling up, there is less of it then, right? It is called the "transient", and to be "fully filled up" happens with a delay a bit later. Take an inductor L in series with a parallel RC and  switch on a constant voltage source, now calculate the transient on the R (use Laplace transform if you are familiar with it)

Comment: Note that a very similar question has been asked here:  [Lumped-element delay lines using LC circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/377176/10475). If you look at the diagram there, note that for each segment, the capacitor charging current is through the inductor which opposes any *change* in the charging current with a voltage across. Thus, it is intuitive that the inductance of the inductor must be a factor in the time constant. If this is the kind of answer you're looking for, I can flesh it out in an answer.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I like both explanations; please put it in an answer, if you like.